# Not able to use Row in django crispy forms

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

Initially my this code was working and it display the rows with many columns.

```
class testForm():

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_method = 'POST'
        self.helper.form_class= ''
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
                Row('user', 'time', 'source'),
                Row('location', 'summary'),

            )
        save_button = Submit('save', 'Save11')
        save_button.field_classes = 'btn-primary btn-large'
        self.helper.add_input(save_button)
```

But now its not working and showing all columns in separate rows rather than combining the columns in one row

Comment: How do you know its not working. Check the code the fields are in same tag or not.

Comment: The div  boxes are there  but column is only one

Comment: What template pack are you using? BTW that layout could be simplified:  Layout(Rows..., Submit('save', 'Save11', css_class='btn-primary btn-large')

Comment: How can i simply that , can you please explain that

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the css of the code. By defult you won't get it in table form. They will be stacked together.

Just define their width  or trying using `float:left`